# how to change default image path of fck editor image copy paste

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using fck editor .with imageupload plugin for drop or paste image for uploading the image on userfiles folder but some thing went wrong and when the image pasted it converts the image into base64.i dont want to convertion of image . please help how it can be solved

Comment: Are you really using FCKeditor? That's totally outdated.  What's your configuration?

Comment: i am using fck for some different font copy from word and pating in web page . i found fck which providing the feature i want .now only one problem for image is it creating  base64 on past .